# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

What is the meaning of this error, what is wrong with the code? I try to execute and I don't know what is the meaning of it? I'm I missing something? Is there commas  missing cause I looked and relooked and didnt find errors howerever it says it haves.

I tried adding commas in every place howerever its doenst works anyway.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">
    var editor; // use a global for the submit and return data rendering in the examples

    $(document).ready(function() {
        editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
            ajax: "../php/staff.php",
            table: "#publicationTable",
            fields: [ {
                    label: "Visualização:",
                    name: "p.status"
                }, {
                    label: "Título da Publicação:",
                    name: "ti.PublicationTitle"
                }, {
                    label: "Tipo de Publicação:",
                    name: "ty.PublicationType"
                }, {
                    label: "Ano:",
                    name: "p.ano"
                }, {
                    label: "Mês:",
                    name: "p.competencia"
                }, {
                    label: "Empresa:",
                    name: "c.razaoSocial"
                }, {
                    label: "Favorecido:",
                    name: "e.nome"
                }
            ]
        } );

        var table = $('#publicationTable').DataTable( {
        lengthChange: true,
        ajax: "../php/staff.php",
        columns: [
            {   data: "p.status",
                render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                    var text = "";
                    if (type == "display") {
                        if (data == "1") {
                            text = "<i class='ace-icon fa fa-rocket'></i>";
                        } else {
                            text = "<i class='ace-icon fa fa-circle'></i>";
                        }
                        data = text
                    }
                    return data;
                },
            },
                { data: "ti.PublicationTitle" },
                { data: "ty.PublicationType" },
                { data: "p.ano" },
                { data: "p.competencia" },
                { data: "c.razaoSocial" },
                { data: "e.nome" },
                {
                            data: "p.id_Publication",
                            render: function(data, type, full){
                                return '<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#infoModal" data-id="' + full[7] + '" id="getPublication" class="blue"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-search-plus bigger-130"></i></a> <a class="red" href="deleteCompany.php?id_Company=' + full[7] + '"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-trash-o bigger-130"></i></a> <a class="orange" data-id="' + full[7] + '" id="blockCompany"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-eye-slash bigger-130"></i></a>';
                            }}
                }
                }
            ],
        } );
    } );

    </script>
```

Comment: your square bracket for columns has an additional } brace

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is after:

```
{
    data: 'p.id_Publication',
    render: function(data, type, full) {
        return '<a data-toggle="modal" ...></i></a>';
    }} // remove these
} //this now closes the render function
}
```

And after making this change:

```
{
    data: 'p.id_Publication',
    render: function(data, type, full) {
        return '<a data-toggle="modal" ...></i></a>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your columns property within DataTables has an additional

> }

use this code block

```
var editor; // use a global for the submit and return data rendering in the examples

$(document).ready(function() {
  editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor({
    ajax: "../php/staff.php",
    table: "#publicationTable",
    fields: [{
      label: "Visualização:",
      name: "p.status"
    }, {
      label: "Título da Publicação:",
      name: "ti.PublicationTitle"
    }, {
      label: "Tipo de Publicação:",
      name: "ty.PublicationType"
    }, {
      label: "Ano:",
      name: "p.ano"
    }, {
      label: "Mês:",
      name: "p.competencia"
    }, {
      label: "Empresa:",
      name: "c.razaoSocial"
    }, {
      label: "Favorecido:",
      name: "e.nome"
    }]
  });

  var table = $('#publicationTable').DataTable({
    lengthChange: true,
    ajax: "../php/staff.php",
    columns: [{
      data: "p.status",
      render: function(data, type, row) {
        var text = "";
        if (type == "display") {
          if (data == "1") {
            text = "<i class='ace-icon fa fa-rocket'></i>";
          } else {
            text = "<i class='ace-icon fa fa-circle'></i>";
          }
          data = text
        }
        return data;
      },
    }, {
      data: "ti.PublicationTitle"
    }, {
      data: "ty.PublicationType"
    }, {
      data: "p.ano"
    }, {
      data: "p.competencia"
    }, {
      data: "c.razaoSocial"
    }, {
      data: "e.nome"
    }, {
      data: "p.id_Publication",
      render: function(data, type, full) {
        return '<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#infoModal" data-id="' + full[7] + '" id="getPublication" class="blue"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-search-plus bigger-130"></i></a> <a class="red" href="deleteCompany.php?id_Company=' + full[7] + '"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-trash-o bigger-130"></i></a> <a class="orange" data-id="' + full[7] + '" id="blockCompany"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-eye-slash bigger-130"></i></a>';
      }
    }],
  });
});
```

you can go to fiddler paste your code and click on Tidy (top bar) to align it which will make it easy for you to find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You had some free floating closing brackets near the end.

Also, I took out `new` on line #4

```
 var editor; // use a global for the submit and return data rendering in the examples

    $(document).ready(function() {
        editor = $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
            ajax: "../php/staff.php",
            table: "#publicationTable",
            fields: [ {
                    label: "Visualização:",
                    name: "p.status"
                }, {
                    label: "Título da Publicação:",
                    name: "ti.PublicationTitle"
                }, {
                    label: "Tipo de Publicação:",
                    name: "ty.PublicationType"
                }, {
                    label: "Ano:",
                    name: "p.ano"
                }, {
                    label: "Mês:",
                    name: "p.competencia"
                }, {
                    label: "Empresa:",
                    name: "c.razaoSocial"
                }, {
                    label: "Favorecido:",
                    name: "e.nome"
                }
            ]
        } );

        var table = $('#publicationTable').DataTable( {
        lengthChange: true,
        ajax: "../php/staff.php",
        columns: [
            {   data: "p.status",
                render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                    var text = "";
                    if (type == "display") {
                        if (data == "1") {
                            text = "<i class='ace-icon fa fa-rocket'></i>";
                        } else {
                            text = "<i class='ace-icon fa fa-circle'></i>";
                        }
                        data = text
                    }
                    return data;
                },
            },
                { data: "ti.PublicationTitle" },
                { data: "ty.PublicationType" },
                { data: "p.ano" },
                { data: "p.competencia" },
                { data: "c.razaoSocial" },
                { data: "e.nome" },
                {
                            data: "p.id_Publication",
                            render: function(data, type, full){
                                return '<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#infoModal" data-id="' + full[7] + '" id="getPublication" class="blue"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-search-plus bigger-130"></i></a> <a class="red" href="deleteCompany.php?id_Company=' + full[7] + '"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-trash-o bigger-130"></i></a> <a class="orange" data-id="' + full[7] + '" id="blockCompany"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-eye-slash bigger-130"></i></a>';

                }
                }
            ],
        } );
    } );
```

Answer (score 0):

This fixes the unexpected token error caused by incorrect brackets. The unexpected token error is a syntax error. 
A specific language construct was expected, but something else was provided. This might be a simple typo -[Mozilla Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Unexpected_token)

```html
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">
    var editor; // use a global for the submit and return data rendering in the examples

    $(document).ready(function() {
    editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor({
      ajax: "../php/staff.php",
      table: "#publicationTable",
      fields: [{
        label: "Visualização:",
        name: "p.status"
      }, {
        label: "Título da Publicação:",
        name: "ti.PublicationTitle"
      }, {
        label: "Tipo de Publicação:",
        name: "ty.PublicationType"
      }, {
        label: "Ano:",
        name: "p.ano"
      }, {
        label: "Mês:",
        name: "p.competencia"
      }, {
        label: "Empresa:",
        name: "c.razaoSocial"
      }, {
        label: "Favorecido:",
        name: "e.nome"
      }]
    });

    var table = $('#publicationTable').DataTable({
        lengthChange: true,
        ajax: "../php/staff.php",
        columns: [
          {
            data: "p.status",
            render: function(data, type, row) {
              var text = "";
              if (type == "display") {
                if (data == "1") {
                  text = "<i class='ace-icon fa fa-rocket'></i>";
                } else {
                  text = "<i class='ace-icon fa fa-circle'></i>";
                }
                data = text
              }
              return data;
            },
          }, 
          {
            data: "ti.PublicationTitle"
          }, 
          {
            data: "ty.PublicationType"
          }, 
          {
            data: "p.ano"
          }, 
          {
            data: "p.competencia"
          }, 
          {
            data: "c.razaoSocial"
          }, 
          {
            data: "e.nome"
          }, 
          {
            data: "p.id_Publication",
            render: function(data, type, full) {
              return '<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#infoModal" data-id="' + full[7] + '" id="getPublication" class="blue"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-search-plus bigger-130"></i></a> <a class="red" href="deleteCompany.php?id_Company=' + full[7] + '"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-trash-o bigger-130"></i></a> <a class="orange" data-id="' + full[7] + '" id="blockCompany"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-eye-slash bigger-130"></i></a>';
            }
          }
      ],
    });
    });
    
  </script>
```